# Selecting Duplicates on All Fields

Tags: query, ms-access, duplication, data-validation, data-cleansing

I have an MS Access (no laughing at the back) database I've used to import a bunch of IIS logs into.

Having looked at the Excel files I pulled these in from, I'm worried going by the dates that some of the IIS files might have full duplicates (i.e. where every single field is identical).

I know how to select duplicates on an individual row, but how can I issue an SQL query that will show me rows where **every** field is identical, so I don't get skewed results?

If possible, some guidance on how to then have these rows deleted from the table without having to do a million delete queries with the individual PK IDs would be great too.

Example data:
[image]

In the above I'd be looking to identify rows 1 and 2 as they are exact duplicates, but 3 and 4 are okay as they share some but not all values. So the report would ideally come back with 1 and 2, so I could then note the IDs and delete all but 1 of the duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then ask the`Query-Wizard`.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I want to find all the rows where there is one or more exact matches (on every field). So not the actual unique ones, but just the non-uniques, so I can remove them (or at least confirm my suspicions about them existing), if that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Updated with a graphic example, hopefully that clarifies.